# Why does the max charge reported by battery health app differ from the "Full Charge Capacity" in About This Mac > System Report?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, battery

In System Information > Power it says

```
Charge Remaining (mAh): 5179
Full Charge Capacity (mAh): 5432
```

But Battery Health 2 reports a Current Charge of 4952mAh and a Current Max of 5097mAh.

[image: Battery Health 2]

Why are they different?

Comment: Your why is a bit unclear. Like why does the developer of the app report different numbers than Apple? Or are you looking for a physics / chemistry explanation why charge estimates (integrating voltage / current over time - mix in measurement errors - and you’ll have numbers that aren’t 100% perfectly repeatable but need to be averaged over time?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The charge can be 100% as shown.

However the health is based on the available capacity now compared to the original capacity when the battery was new. The charge holding capacity degrades over time.

So the 100% charge is 100% of the current capacity.

So, having missed the bit about comparison, the difference can be due to the system not having had an smc reset recently and the results can tend to drift over time. fwiw I have found that battery apps can give a good account with more detail, but if the system says it will shutdown at a certain value then it will be based on the system’s recorded value.